# Handle inputs from a gamepad with Processing for Android

Tags: android, input, processing, gamepad

I’m trying to use [Processing for Android](https://android.processing.org/) to get inputs from a physical game controller (with buttons and joysticks).

I am using the Android [documentation on controller actions](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/game-controllers/controller-input#java) as a guide.

Tl;dr: I'm struggling to find how to override the necessary callbacks (`onGenericMotionEvent()`, `onKeyDown()`, `onKeyUp()`) in the context of Processing since it instantiates the `Activity` and `View` itself.

Here's what I have managed so far:

1. Compile Processing examples to the device (specifically the RG353V, an Android-based handheld gaming console from Anbernic)
2. Use `android.view.InputDevice` to make a list of input devices and output their names to the console
3. Filter the input devices that are game controllers
4. Register an input device listener to receive notifications about when input devices are added, removed or changed using `inputManager.registerInputDeviceListener()`
5. Get the main activity with `Activity activity = getActivity()`
6. Get the root view with `ViewGroup rootView = activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);`

I now want to capture button/joystick events but this is where my trouble starts.

All the examples I found involve implementing a custom view and overriding `onGenericMotionEvent()` for joystick events, and `onKeyDown()`/`onKeyUp()` for button events.

Only [Processing instantiates the main Activity and View](https://github.com/processing/processing-android/blob/e39526b3faa2dd95477b2ad93dbf72fd481a7f20/debug/apps/simple/src/main/java/simple/MainActivity.java) on its own, so I don't know to override those callbacks. Is it even possible to override a method on an instance of a class?

I was hoping to find something similar to `registerInputDeviceListener()` in the `InputManager` class or `registerListener()` in the `SensorManager` class, but I haven't found a method that would allow to register callbacks for button and joystick input in the `InputDevice` class in the same way.

I'll be grateful for any pointers.

PS: I posted a [feature request](https://github.com/processing/processing-android/issues/715) on the Processing for Android repo.

Comment: Seems similar to an [older closed issue request](https://github.com/processing/processing-android/issues/86). I took a quick look at [PApplet.java](https://github.com/processing/processing-android/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PApplet.java) which is probably where some/any changes would be. You'll have to fork the repo for customization. Given that gamepads could have multiple buttons pressed at the same time I'm not sure if they fit in the existing event framework: https://github.com/processing/processing-android/tree/master/core/src/processing/event Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! That’s the answer I feared but it’s good to know so I can stop looking for imaginary methods. Appreciate you digging this old issue and the extra guidance 